# Azure Data Factory (ADF) copy activity results or loggings don't have source and sink location information

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-log-analytics

The **Copy Activity** result doesn't show the source and sink location (file path or server etc.) Not from the ADF monitor or Log Analytics. It only shows the source and sink type. It is impossible to trace where the data is copied from and to. Does anyone know how to track that information?

**Input**:

```
{
    "source": {
        "type": "ParquetSource",
        "storeSettings": {
            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
            "recursive": true,
            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
        },
        "formatSettings": {
            "type": "ParquetReadSettings"
        }
    },
    "sink": {
        "type": "ParquetSink",
        "storeSettings": {
            "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
        },
        "formatSettings": {
            "type": "ParquetWriteSettings"
        }
    },
    "enableStaging": false,
    "translator": {
        "type": "TabularTranslator",
        "typeConversion": true,
        "typeConversionSettings": {
            "allowDataTruncation": true,
            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
{
    "dataRead": 1362,
    "dataWritten": 1362,
    "filesRead": 1,
    "filesWritten": 1,
    "sourcePeakConnections": 3,
    "sinkPeakConnections": 2,
    "copyDuration": 97,
    "throughput": 0.227,
    "errors": [],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (Canada Central)",
    "usedDataIntegrationUnits": 4,
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "DataMovement",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.06666666666666667,
                "unit": "DIUHours"
            }
        ],
        "totalBillableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.06666666666666667,
                "unit": "DIUHours"
            }
        ]
    },
    "usedParallelCopies": 1,
    "executionDetails": [
        {
            "source": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFS",
                "region": "Canada Central"
            },
            "sink": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFS",
                "region": "Canada Central"
            },
            "status": "Succeeded",
            "start": "10/3/2023, 2:33:57 PM",
            "duration": 97,
            "usedDataIntegrationUnits": 4,
            "usedParallelCopies": 1,
            "profile": {
                "queue": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 89
                },
                "transfer": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 6,
                    "details": {
                        "listingSource": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFS",
                            "workingDuration": 0
                        },
                        "readingFromSource": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFS",
                            "workingDuration": 0
                        },
                        "writingToSink": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFS",
                            "workingDuration": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "detailedDurations": {
                "queuingDuration": 89,
                "transferDuration": 6
            }
        }
    ],
    "dataConsistencyVerification": {
        "VerificationResult": "NotVerified"
    },
    "reportLineageToPurview": {
        "status": "Succeeded",
        "durationInSecond": "1"
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Zhiyu, there's an option to 'Enable Logging' in the Copy Activity. It is under 'Settings' tab in Copy Activity. You would have to provide a storage location to store the logs. Worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It doesn't have the location data either.

Answer (score 0):

As @Yash Tamakuwala mentioned, enabling logging in the copy activity provides details on the copied file. However, it only displays the copied file name, not the file location, as shown below:

[image]

To obtain the file location of the source and sink, use the [dataset REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/datasets/get?tabs=HTTP). Locate the source and sink datasets in the Copy activity JSON. Then, input the required details into the REST API and execute it, as demonstrated below:

[image]

The result will appear as follows:

[image]

However, if the path is provided dynamically, only the variable will be displayed instead of the file path.

Comment: Thanks for your help. We are using ADF copy activity for the production environment and there will be hundreds of data migrations each day. And we need this information to be part of the Log Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to update the answer.

Inside the Copy activity, click 'auto-generate' inside 'User Properties'. It will include the source and sink information.
[image]